# Stripe PHP checkout API : Error: Exception: Received unknown parameter: shipping

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Im trying to pass shipping details to the checkout session built with:

```
\Stripe\Checkout\Session::create
```

But I guet this error:

```
Breaking news… Error:   Exception: Received unknown parameter: shipping (in /myserver/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php line 38)
```

Except from that part the process works fine. Even if I pass "shipping" => null it doesn't give the error.

In the API reference it just shows the "shipping" data array as an optional attributes.

Here is the complete array I'm passing to the session::create

```
 [billing_address_collection] => required
    [payment_method_types] => Array
        (
            [0] => card
        )
[line_items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [price_data] => Array
                    (
                        [currency] => eur
                        [product_data] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => MEMBER 004: Dark Storm
                                [description] => sizes:'S-M'
                                [images] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg
                                    )

                            )

                        [unit_amount] => 1995
                    )

                [quantity] => 1
            )

    )

[mode] => payment
[success_url] => http://mywebsite.com/succes/
[cancel_url] => http://mywebsite.com/cancel/
[shipping_address_collection] => Array
    (
        [0] => ES
    )

[shipping] => Array
    (
        [address] => Array
            (
                [city] => Barcelona
                [country] => ES
                [line1] => Street name 81
                [line2] => 12
                [postal_code] => 09028
                [state] => Catalunya
            )

        [name] => My name
    )

[customer_email] => myname@gmail.com
```

)

Comment: shot in the dark, have you tried setting the `shippable` (boolean) property - _Whether this product is a shipped good. Only applicable to products of `type=good`._

Comment: I tried it, it gives me this error: 
Exception: Received unknown parameters: shippable, shipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass a shipping address into a Checkout session like this. It is not a parameter of the [create endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create). The `shipping` [attribute](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-shipping) of the session object will be populated with the customer shipping address when you use the [`shipping_address_collection` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection), as I see in your example.

So, you need to remove the invalid `shipping` parameter and instead inspect that on the result.

Comment: So, you mean I cannot collect the shipping information before getting to the checkout stripe-hosted page? I just put the shipping_adress_collection there to check if that could fix it, but actually I don't need to specify which countries are valid for shipping in my case.

Comment: If you already collect shipping information then there's no need to use Checkout's shipping address collection. You can just leave this off entirely and either put it on a pre-existing `customer` address (if you're using one) or just store it in your own systems for shipping after payment.

Comment: My idea was to put all sensitive data stored in Stripe since I'm using a very basic CMS for the website using stripe so my client just needs to check the purchased/shipping orders inside Stripe. But I need to know the shipping info before getting to the Stripe checkout page to calculate the shipping costs, (My client has a very complex criteria for shipping costs worldwide)

Comment: In which case I'd recommend creating a customer and putting the shipping address there, and then providing that existing customer for the checkout session.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-address
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer

Comment: If someone ends up with the same issue, I ended up asking the user it's shipping country (on my website side) to assign a shipping cost and then just collect shipping adress in Stripe checkout page with the country assigned so it doesn't show the field country.